# Error while closing the question

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I recently visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21879660/696134), it is a duplicate of other question, and I tried to close the question but it gives error while clicking question which comes in the list. Please see attachment, so not able to close the question.

I have checked in 2 different browsers Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.107) and Firefox Mozila (Version 22.0)

[image: Error]
[image: Error1]
[image: Error2]

Comment: Have you refreshed the page and retried? Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Yes I have tried hard refresh. I have tried in 2 different browsers, and both gives the same error. If you can guide I can inspect as I have some experience of web.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. And I can see one close vote that came in after you posted this.

Comment: F12 to open the dev tools in Chrome - anything come up in red?

Comment: yes I added screenshot for the same, it happens when I click on the question.

Comment: You have 8 errors there click the red x button - what comes up?

Comment: Actually I kept trying to hard refresh so those error was no more there but now I see 1 error which is shown in red, I have attached screenshot. Now I have kept it open as it is.

Comment: Do you have any extensions? Try disabling them and see if that fixes the issue. Are you browsing over https?

Comment: I tried disabling extensions and found AdBlock 2.6.18 was creating problem. After disabling extension it worked. Can this be resolved? just curious what could be the reason.

Comment: Nothing we can do to resolve it - I have no idea why AdBlock would block that link (possibly app-store in the title?), but this is something to report to them to resolve.